# Spark - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Map output statuses were N bytes which exceeds akka framesize

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.6. Here is the code:

```
val records = sc.textFile(filename).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) val partitionCount = records.getNumPartitions
println(s"Number of Paritions: " + partitionCount)

println(s"Number record count: " + records.count)

val idRecs = records.map(x => { MyServiceHelper.getIdRecord(x) }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

idRecs.take(300).foreach(println) records.unpersist(false)

val kk = idRecs.reduceByKey({(a, b) => b ::: a}, partitionCount*4)
```

I am getting the following exception -

```
MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Map output statuses were 294710029 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize
```

This happens when my input size is large (about 4TB, ~5 billion records).  I tried the same code with about 1TB and did not face this isse. You can see I am not sending any data to the Driver, except `idRecs.take(300)` - each idRec size is about 400 bytes.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this??

Comment: The fix was to increase the mem size of the driver.  But I did get time to debug the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

So, I ran into the same issue and decided to investigate. It turns out that while it is not obvious, (potentially large) data *is* indeed send back and forth between the driver and the workers in the form of `MapOutputStatuses` (which, as I understand it, is essentially a map of where the data is located on the workers). This map is unbounded in size (according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5077) Jira ticket) and it grows with the number of tasks. Processing large amount of data often requires a large number of tasks, which is why you run into the problem when the input size increases.

The solution is indeed to increase mem size on the driver and also increase `akka.framesize` to accommodate the larger map.

Please note, that according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1239) Jira ticket the problem has been resolved in Spark 2.0.

Comment: I have not tried this with Spark 2.0.  Dis it work for you in 2.0?  There is another related jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12837.  Although jira claims that the issue is fixed in 2.0.1 but if you read the comment, it still exists.

Comment: I have not seen this issue in any of my 2.0 projects, but none of those projects run with as much data or as many partitions as my 1.6 job. In other words I don't know for sure that it has been fixed in 2.0 - I simply noticed the "resolved for 2.0" on the jira-ticket...

Comment: I came cross this error in 1.6.0. Same code running on 2.2 is fine.